# API Cloudflare статистика сайта в JSON

Tags: api, cloudflare

интересует, как через API Cloudflare получить статистику посещений своего сайта в домене второго уровня в JSON (количество посетителей и откуда они). Спасибо. Возможно ли через запрос в адресной строке, или только через cURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел много информации на [cloudflare](https://api.cloudflare.com).
С помощью этого API можно получить много информации по своему ресурсу (после его настройки по инструкции cloudflare). Работает с ресурсами в домене второго уровня, с третьим и далее не работает.

Делал через cURL на Ubuntu, например:

```sh
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/settings" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: auth-key и идентификатор зоны, надеюсь, фейковые? если нет, рекомендую срочно перегенерировать auth-key.